# Make a good url without the index with magento

Tags: php, magento, module, url-rewriting

I want to make a phtml file witch shows products from a specific brand.

The url needs to look like:

```
brands/Subway
brands/Mcdonalds
brands/Lego
brands/Barbie
brands/Duplo
brands/.....
```

How can i make this url work where the brand is a variable.

I have tried to make a module but in that case I get an url like brands/index/brands/Subway

I also don't want to make a rewrite for every brand (100+)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom router in your module to handle routes like `brands/Subway`.
Here is what you need.

First you need to have the pages working without rewrites.
Let's assume that at this url `mysite.com/brands/index/index` - you have the brand list
and at the url `mysite.com/brands/index/view/id/12` - you have the brand with id 12.

In your config.xml you need to add this inside the `<global>` tag:

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <[namespace]_[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </[namespace]_[module]>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

This will add a new router to the existing ones.
Now the router class `app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Controller/Router.php`:

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract{
    public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('[module]', $this);
        return $this;
    }
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $check = array();
        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
        if ($parts[0] == 'brands'){//if url key starts with 'brands'
            if (!isset($parts[1])){ //if the url is just 'brands' - then redirect to brand list
                return false;//do nothing...the request will be handled by the default router and you will see `brands/index/index/`.
            }
            elseif ($parts[1] == 'index'){//if your controller is named differently change 'index' to your controller name
                return false; //do nothing...the request will be handled by the default router and you will see `brands/index/index/`.
            }
            else {
                //if a name is specified
                //get the entities with that name.
                $collection = Mage::getModel('[module]/[entity]')->getCollection()
                    //if the field is named differently change 'name' to your field name.
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $parts[1]);
                $collection->getSelect()->limit(1);//limit to only one
                $itemId = (int)$collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
                //redirect to 'brands/index/view/id/$itemId'
                $request->setModuleName('brands')
                    ->setControllerName('index') //if your controller is named differently change 'index' to your controller name
                    ->setActionName('view') //if your action is named differently change 'view' to action name
                    ->setParam('id', $itemId);
                $request->setAlias(
                    Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                    $urlKey
                );
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

That's it. Clear the cache and give it a try.

Comment: I can't get it work. right now the url is /merk/index/view/name/Subway. I have made a global with the observer `<global>
  <controller_front_init_routers>
   <observers>
    <SpeelgoedwinkelXL_Brands>
     <class>SpeelgoedwinkelXL_Brands_Controller_Router</class>
     <method>initControllerRouters</method>
    </SpeelgoedwinkelXL_Brands>
   </observers>
  </controller_front_init_routers>
 </global>`
In the router.php i changed the function intiControllerRouters to echo 'testing'; exit; but it doesn't put out anything on the screen. Or is it not possible to debug the router?

Comment: Sorry my bad...I forgot an xml tag `<events>`. I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You could create a rewrite rule in your .htaccess (the one that's in the root directory).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^brand/(.+)$ /brands/index/brands?brand=$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

With this if your url is:

> www.yoursite.com/brands/index/brands?brand=MyBrandName

You'll see:

> www.yoursite.com/brand/MyBrandName

Hope it helps!